# Correct Translation of "Endure and Persist"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'm looking to get a tattoo of some Latin that translates to "Endure and Persist". When I throw it into google translate I get "perdurare et perseverare". I just want to make sure that's correct.

Additionally, if there are any Latin phrases that you'd recommend that are relating to perseverance, the struggle of life, or enduring hardship that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Ignore Google Translate. That it continues to be used for Latin is criminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many, many ways to translate this into Latin (just like you have a dozen ways to say this in English).

However, I will offer what I think is the best way, taken directly from the Roman poet Catullus himself:

> nec quae fugit sectāre, nec miser vīve,
> sed obstinātā mente **perfer, obdūrā**.

> And follow now she who flees, nor live pitifully,
> But with an hardened mind **persist, endure**.

The whole poem is a great (and well-known) exhortation to flee from unrequited love and endure the pain that follows. You really can't go wrong using this expression.

You can add the *et* in between if you like, but the abbreviated style appeals to me, and of course is the direct wording of the poem.

Note that this is a command given to a single person, such as one you might tell yourself or someone else. It would not be used to address a group of people.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much!